# Validate in:post_fieds in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

It's posible to validate request with values from requests.

Simple example, I have FormRequest object with rules:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'id' => 'required|integer',
        'languages' => 'required|array',
        'default_language' => 'required|in:languages',
    ];
}
```

How to validate default_language which values must in languages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use   in_array:anotherfield   validation like this:

```
 public function rules() {
return [
    'id' => 'required|integer',
    'languages' => 'required|array',
    'default_language' => 'required|in_array:languages',
];
```

}

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-in-array